# Can I programmatically close a context menu in jsTree?

Tags: jstree

Is there a way I can programatically close a context menu in jsTree? I implemented a way to open the context menus on hover using show_contextmenu but I need to close it when the mouse leaves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, looking through the code I found what I needed, there is a property called `hide_on_mouseleave` which I just set to true in the source and it started working as expected.

If that doesn't work, this is the code used to close the context menu executed when `hide_on_mouseleave` property is true:

```
$.vakata.context.hide();
```

Comment: Note that now the property is named as `hide_onmouseleave`. F.e. `$.vakata.context.settings.hide_onmouseleave = 1`

Comment: Using `hide_onmouseleave=1`, if the pop up is displayed below a tree node, but the user moves the mouse out of the tree node but never enters the pop up, the mouse does not leave and the pop up remains stranded.  I used `$(document)  
    .on("mouseleave", function (e) {  
   $.vakata.context.hide();  
 });`